# Spring bean autowiring based on property

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I want to specify in property file, which bean will be autowired.
I found the solutions but all of them are using **@Profile** annotation, which means that they are based on specified profile, not specified property. 

I did it in that way:

```
@Configuration
public class WebServiceFactory {
    @Value("${webservice}")
    private String webService;
    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    private GraphQLService graphQLService;
    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    private RestService restService;

    @Primary
    @Bean
    WebService getWebService() {
        switch (webService) {
            case "graphQlService":
                return graphQLService;
            case "restService":
                return restService;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported web service.");
        }
    }
}
```

Bean type I want to autowire is interface **WebService**, **GraphQLService** and **RestService** are it's implementations.
Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to inject a bean into another based on a property file ? Or you have many Webservices implementations and many GraphQSService implementations and you want to inject a specific implementation at runtime ?

Comment: Yes, I have application.properties file, and there is value "webservice". Spring should read this value and inject proper bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the normal configuration of Spring.

```
class A{
 B bBean;
 ...//setters/getters here.
}

class B{}
```

You can have a configuration file (It also can be a configuration class)

```
<bean id = "a" class = "A">
      <property name="bBean" ref="b"/>     
   </bean>

<bean id = "b" class = "B">   
   </bean>
```

The bBean configuration can be in a different file, so you can import it from you classpath. Instead of using a property file you use a configuration file in the classpath o systemfile. If B is a different implementation then you modify your config file with the right class.

Comment: Thanks a lot fo your answer, but is there any way to do this programmatically, using annotations?

Comment: Why do you want to use annotations ? Annotations use fixed values, it's more limited. You can do the same using configuration files or classes.

Comment: You're right, in that case it would be better to use xml config. Thanks!

Comment: Note, that you can also use class configuration. with @bean annotation. And do the same as with the xml file. The classes are the same as files.